# Como puedo ingresar por consola objetos a un arraylist? en JAVA

Tags: poo, arraylist

Necesito hacer un arreglo de objetos en el cual pueda ingresar objetos a un arraylist, de forma que cada objeto contenga varios valores diferentes como la clave del producto, precio, descripción y cantidad etc

Comment: Dependera mucho del lenguaje de programacion, por ejemplo en C++ es suficiente un apuntador a dicho objeto ya instanciado, en otros lenguajes podrias crear un bucle que lea N objetos seguidamente instanciar(crear el objeto) y agregar al arraylist. saludos

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Con todos los respetos, tu pregunta es "de 1º de java". Tan sencillo como crear una clase que contenga todas las propiedades (clave del producto, precio, descripción y cantidad) y que la `E` en `ArrayList<E>` sea esa clase.

Answer (score 3):

Hola buenas para poder ingresar objetos por consola debes hacerlo atributo por atributo.
Para ello puedes crear una clase como la siguiente:

```
package buenagente;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class Objeto {
    private String producto;
    private double precio;
    private String descripcion;
    private int cantidad;

    public Objeto() {
    }
    
    
    
    public Objeto(String producto, double precio, String descripcion, int cantidad) {
        this.producto = producto;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public String getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(String producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Objeto{" + "producto=" + producto + ", precio=" + precio + ", descripcion=" + descripcion + ", cantidad=" + cantidad + '}';
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Después en la clase Main debes declarar la clase Scanner para poder introducir por consola. Para introducir un objeto lo que hacemos es ir poniendo atributo a atributo a partir de los setter. Después añadimos el objeto al ArrayList. Un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
package buenagente;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class BuenaGente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        ArrayList<Objeto> lista = new ArrayList();
        
        Objeto o1 = new Objeto("pizza", 3.5, "grande", 2);
        lista.add(o1);
        Objeto o2 = new Objeto("hamburguesa", 4.6, "media", 3);
        lista.add(o2);
        
        Objeto o3 = new Objeto();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el producto: ");
        o3.setProducto(teclado.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Introduzca el precio: ");
        o3.setPrecio(teclado.nextDouble());
        System.out.println("Introduzca la descripción: ");
        o3.setDescripcion(teclado.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad: ");
        o3.setCantidad(teclado.nextInt());
        
        lista.add(o3);
        
        for (Objeto obj : lista) {
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    }
```